# Tomcat7 application fails to start

Tags: tomcat, maven, jetty, tapestry, cometd

I have got a following problem that I am not sure how to solve. I believe that there is some dependency incompatiblity problem, but I dont know how to check.

Does anyone have any idea where to start?

I am using maven to manage my dependencies. The dependancy that I think is the root of the problem is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lazan</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry-cometd</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.14</version> 
    </dependency>
```

However I am not sure how to check underline problem.

The logs can be seen bellow.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter app
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'PushManager': Error invoking constructor public org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.internal.PushManagerImpl(org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer,org.slf4j.Logger,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.ComponentJSONRenderer,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TypeCoercer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdGlobals): Exception constructing service 'BayeuxServer': Error invoking method public static org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdModule.buildBayeuxServer(org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.Authorizers,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.SubscriptionListeners,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdGlobals): Exception constructing service 'BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter': Error invoking constructor public org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.CometdHttpServletRequestFilter(org.apache.tapestry5.services.ApplicationGlobals,java.util.Map,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.RegistryShutdownHub,java.lang.String): javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1467)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking constructor public org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.internal.PushManagerImpl(org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer,org.slf4j.Logger,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.ComponentJSONRenderer,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TypeCoercer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdGlobals): Exception constructing service 'BayeuxServer': Error invoking method public static org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdModule.buildBayeuxServer(org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.Authorizers,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.SubscriptionListeners,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdGlobals): Exception constructing service 'BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter': Error invoking constructor public org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.CometdHttpServletRequestFilter(org.apache.tapestry5.services.ApplicationGlobals,java.util.Map,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.RegistryShutdownHub,java.lang.String): javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructorInvoker.invoke(ConstructorInvoker.java:57)org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'BayeuxServer': Error invoking method public static org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdModule.buildBayeuxServer(org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.Authorizers,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.SubscriptionListeners,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdGlobals): Exception constructing service 'BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter': Error invoking constructor public org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.CometdHttpServletRequestFilter(org.apache.tapestry5.services.ApplicationGlobals,java.util.Map,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.RegistryShutdownHub,java.lang.String): javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:75)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
    at $BayeuxServer_20153764561c.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $BayeuxServer_20153764561c.addListener(Unknown Source)
    at org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.internal.PushManagerImpl.<init>(PushManagerImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructorInvoker.invoke(ConstructorInvoker.java:48)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking method public static org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdModule.buildBayeuxServer(org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.Authorizers,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.SubscriptionListeners,org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdGlobals): Exception constructing service 'BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter': Error invoking constructor public org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.CometdHttpServletRequestFilter(org.apache.tapestry5.services.ApplicationGlobals,java.util.Map,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.RegistryShutdownHub,java.lang.String): javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.LoggingInvokableWrapper.invoke(LoggingInvokableWrapper.java:42)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructionPlan.createObject(ConstructionPlan.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AdvisorStackBuilder.createObject(AdvisorStackBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:54)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter': Error invoking constructor public org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.CometdHttpServletRequestFilter(org.apache.tapestry5.services.ApplicationGlobals,java.util.Map,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.RegistryShutdownHub,java.lang.String): javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:75)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
    at $BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter_201537645620.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter_201537645620.getBayeuxServer(Unknown Source)
    at org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdModule.buildBayeuxServer(CometdModule.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:50)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: Error invoking constructor public org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.CometdHttpServletRequestFilter(org.apache.tapestry5.services.ApplicationGlobals,java.util.Map,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.RegistryShutdownHub,java.lang.String): javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructionPlan.createObject(ConstructionPlan.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.createObject(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AdvisorStackBuilder.createObject(AdvisorStackBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:54)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    ... 114 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking constructor public org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.CometdHttpServletRequestFilter(org.apache.tapestry5.services.ApplicationGlobals,java.util.Map,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.RegistryShutdownHub,java.lang.String): javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructorInvoker.invoke(ConstructorInvoker.java:57)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.LoggingInvokableWrapper.invoke(LoggingInvokableWrapper.java:42)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    ... 134 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.ServletHttpServletRequestFilter.<init>(ServletHttpServletRequestFilter.java:36)
    at org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.CometdHttpServletRequestFilter.<init>(CometdHttpServletRequestFilter.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructorInvoker.invoke(ConstructorInvoker.java:48)
    ... 136 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:549)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:191)
    at org.atmosphere.cometd.CometdServlet.init(CometdServlet.java:50)
    at org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.ServletHttpServletRequestFilter.<init>(ServletHttpServletRequestFilter.java:28)
    ... 142 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:233)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:296)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:284)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:1100)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:500)
    ... 145 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:229)
    ... 149 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.eclipse.jetty.io.ThreadLocalBuffers
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.BuffersFactory.newBuffers(BuffersFactory.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketBuffers.<init>(WebSocketBuffers.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.<init>(WebSocketFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.<init>(WebSocketFactory.java:97)
    at org.atmosphere.container.JettyWebSocketUtil.getFactory(JettyWebSocketUtil.java:79)
    at org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.<init>(JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:55)
    ... 154 more
```

web.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0"> 
    Flow WebApplication

```
<!-- The only significant configuration for Tapestry 5, this informs Tapestry of where to look for pages, components and mixins. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>tapestry.app-package</param-name>
    <param-value>com.bomahabo.flow.tapestry</param-value>
</context-param>   

<context-param>
    <param-name>tapestry.prod-modules</param-name>
    <param-value>com.bomahabo.flow.tapestry.services.execution.ProductionModeModule</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>tapestry.dev-modules</param-name>
    <param-value>com.bomahabo.flow.tapestry.services.execution.DevelopmentModeModule</param-value>
</context-param> 
<context-param>
    <param-name>tapestry.qa-modules</param-name>
    <param-value>com.bomahabo.flow.tapestry.services.execution.QAModeModule</param-value>
</context-param> 

<filter>
    <filter-name>app</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter</filter-class>    
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>app</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>  
</filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404</location>
</error-page>
```

dependency tree

```
+- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-hibernate:jar:5.3.6:compile
|  +- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-hibernate-core:jar:5.3.6:compile
|  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
|  |  +- geronimo-spec:geronimo-spec-jta:jar:1.0-M1:runtime
|  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
|  |  +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
|  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
|  \- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-core:jar:5.3.6:compile
|     +- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-json:jar:5.3.6:compile
|     \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.3:compile
|        \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
+- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-upload:jar:5.3.6:compile
|  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:compile
|  \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
+- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-yuicompressor:jar:5.3.6:compile
|  \- com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.7:compile
|     \- rhino:js:jar:1.6R7:compile
+- org.got5:tapestry5-jquery:jar:3.3.3:compile
|  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
+- org.lazan:tapestry-cometd:jar:0.9.14:compile
|  \- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-cometd:jar:1.0.0:compile
|     +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-server:jar:2.4.3:compile
|     |  +- org.cometd.java:bayeux-api:jar:2.4.3:compile
|     |  +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-common:jar:2.4.3:compile
|     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:7.6.4.v20120524:compile
|     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:jar:7.6.4.v20120524:compile
|     +- org.cometd.java:cometd-websocket-jetty:jar:2.4.3:compile
|     |  +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-client:jar:2.4.3:compile
|     |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:7.6.4.v20120524:compile
|     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:jar:7.6.4.v20120524:compile
|     +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-annotations:jar:2.4.3:compile
|     \- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:jar:1.0.0:compile
|        +- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-compat-jbossweb:jar:1.0.0:compile
|        +- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-compat-tomcat:jar:1.0.0:compile
|        \- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-compat-tomcat7:jar:1.0.0:compile
+- org.got5:tapestry5-highcharts:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- org.tynamo:tapestry-security:jar:0.4.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-web:jar:1.2.0:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:jar:1.2.0:compile
|  |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
|  +- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-ioc:jar:5.3.4:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-func:jar:5.3.4:compile
|  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
|  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry5-annotations:jar:5.3.4:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.tapestry:plastic:jar:5.3.4:compile
|  +- org.tynamo:tynamo-common:jar:0.0.3:compile
|  \- org.tynamo:tapestry-exceptionpage:jar:0.1.2:compile
+- org.tynamo:tapestry-resteasy:jar:0.3.0:compile
|  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:2.3.0.GA:compile
|  |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.3.0.GA:compile
|  |  +- org.scannotation:scannotation:jar:1.0.3:compile
|  |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
|  |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
|  \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:2.3.0.GA:compile
|     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.4:compile
|     |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
|     \- com.sun.xml.stream:sjsxp:jar:1.0.1:compile
|        \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0:compile
+- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jettison-provider:jar:2.3.4.Final:compile
|  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.1:compile
+- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:jar:2.2.0.GA:compile
|  \- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6:compile
+- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.3.22:compile
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:compile
|  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
|  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.9:compile
|  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.9:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
|  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
|  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
|  |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
|  +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
+- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.10:compile
+- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.21:compile
+- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:compile
|  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
+- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1:compile
+- net.coobird:thumbnailator:jar:0.4.2:compile
+- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-test:jar:5.3.6:test
|  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:135:test
|  |  +- mx4j:mx4j-tools:jar:3.0.1:test
|  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.9:test
|  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.8:test
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
|  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:test
|  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-android-driver:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  |     +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:test
|  |  |     +- org.json:json:jar:20080701:test
|  |  |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:10.0.1:test
|  |  |        \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:test
|  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  |  \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.9:test
|  |  |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:test
|  |  |     |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:test
|  |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.2:test
|  |  |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.9:test
|  |  |     +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:test
|  |  |     +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.15:test
|  |  |     \- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.5:test
|  |  |        \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:test
|  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:test
|  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.3.0:test
|  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-iphone-driver:jar:2.14.0:test
|  |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:2.14.0:test
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
|  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
|  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
|  +- jetty:org.mortbay.jetty:jar:5.1.12:test
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:compile
|  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:compile
|  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:compile
|  +- org.apache.tomcat:dbcp:jar:6.0.30:test
|  +- org.apache.tomcat:coyote:jar:6.0.30:test
|  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:servlet-api:jar:6.0.30:test
|  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:juli:jar:6.0.30:test
|  \- org.apache.tomcat:catalina:jar:6.0.30:test
|     \- org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:jar:6.0.30:test
+- org.testng:testng:jar:5.12.1:test
|  \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
+- org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.5.2:test
\- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
```

I would also like to mention that this runs successfully whey I run it locally - that is using maven-jetty plugin but when I deploy it to Tomcat 7 it fails.

It looks to me like tomcat is missing some dependency that is of jettys but I am not sure what should I add

Any ideas anyone?

thank you  and happy new year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to deploy the cometd demo to tomcat 6.0.36. Source code here https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-cometd-demo

Firstly, I built the war with the "tapestry-test" dependency in my pom.xml. I deployed the war to tomcat and got a similar exception to you (listed below). I unzipped the war file and looked in WEB-INF/lib and noticed that there were two different versions of the jetty jars:

```
jetty-client-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
jetty-continuation-7.0.0.v20091005.jar
jetty-http-7.0.0.v20091005.jar
jetty-io-7.0.0.v20091005.jar
jetty-jmx-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
jetty-util-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
jetty-websocket-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
```

As we discussed earlier, I was suspicious that the transitive jetty dependencies in tapestry-test were the culprit. I commented out the tapestry-test dependency in my pom and did a clean build. The jetty jars in the war were now all the same version. Result!

```
jetty-client-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
jetty-continuation-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
jetty-http-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
jetty-io-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
jetty-jmx-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
jetty-util-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
jetty-websocket-7.6.4.v20120524.jar
```

So, it seems that even though tapestry-test has a scope of "test", it is still able to affect the dependencies that are included in the war artifact. Maven uses a "nearest declaration wins" strategy when resolving dependencies and I guess that the jetty dependencies coming from tapestry-test are "nearer" than the jetty dependencies coming from tapestry-cometd.

So, I can see two possible fixes:

1. Remove the "tapestry-test" dependency from your pom.xml if you don't need it
2. Add 3 dependencies to your pom.xml for "jetty-continuation", "jetty-http" and "jetty-io" specifying version 7.6.4.v20120524.

Here's the error I initially got:

```
[INFO] cpr.AtmosphereFramework Installed AtmosphereInterceptor CometD/Bayeux Protocol.
[ERROR] cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver failed to create comet support class: class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket, error: null
[ERROR] cpr.AtmosphereFramework Failed to initialize Atmosphere Framework
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:233)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:296)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:284)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:1100)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:500)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:191)
        at org.atmosphere.cometd.CometdServlet.init(CometdServlet.java:50)
        at org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.ServletHttpServletRequestFilter.<init>(ServletHttpServletRequestFilter.java:28)
        at org.lazan.t5.cometd.web.CometdHttpServletRequestFilter.<init>(CometdHttpServletRequestFilter.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructorInvoker.invoke(ConstructorInvoker.java:48)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.LoggingInvokableWrapper.invoke(LoggingInvokableWrapper.java:42)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructionPlan.createObject(ConstructionPlan.java:60)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.createObject(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:61)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AdvisorStackBuilder.createObject(AdvisorStackBuilder.java:63)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:54)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
        at $BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter_e278bc1997a1.delegate(Unknown Source)
        at $BayeuxServerHttpServletRequestFilter_e278bc1997a1.getBayeuxServer(Unknown Source)
        at org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.CometdModule.buildBayeuxServer(CometdModule.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:50)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.LoggingInvokableWrapper.invoke(LoggingInvokableWrapper.java:42)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructionPlan.createObject(ConstructionPlan.java:60)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:60)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AdvisorStackBuilder.createObject(AdvisorStackBuilder.java:63)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:54)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
        at $BayeuxServer_e278bc19979d.delegate(Unknown Source)
        at $BayeuxServer_e278bc19979d.addListener(Unknown Source)
        at org.lazan.t5.cometd.services.internal.PushManagerImpl.<init>(PushManagerImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructorInvoker.invoke(ConstructorInvoker.java:48)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.LoggingInvokableWrapper.invoke(LoggingInvokableWrapper.java:42)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructionPlan.createObject(ConstructionPlan.java:60)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.createObject(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:61)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AdvisorStackBuilder.createObject(AdvisorStackBuilder.java:63)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:54)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.eagerLoadService(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:86)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.performRegistryStartup(RegistryImpl.java:320)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryWrapper.performRegistryStartup(RegistryWrapper.java:80)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.init(TapestryFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:229)
        ... 129 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/io/nio/AsyncConnection
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        at org.atmosphere.container.JettyWebSocketUtil.getFactory(JettyWebSocketUtil.java:79)
        at org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.<init>(JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:55)
        ... 134 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.AsyncConnection
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        ... 160 more
```

Comment: I am afraid that it is a bit more stranger then that. I have tried again various combinations and this is what I have found out. If I run 32bit Tomcat 6 without any changes it crashes like yours (as you have said due to the diff versions). However if I run it on 32bit Tomcat 7 it works ok. If I run it under 64bit Tomcat 7 it crashes under any combinations. BTW do you think that it would be possible to upgrade dependency on cometd-websocket-jetty to 2.5.1 it updates jetty related dependencies to the same version 7.6.8 I think

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the underlying dependency of `tapestry-cometd` on `Atmosphere`.

It might be a maven issue. You can checkout your maven dependencies and see if there is another version of `Atmosphere` or `JWebSocket`.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same problem, as I am getting error on Tomcat 6 as well (I am using AWS to host so I am not sure how can I add some libraries that they are saying). I have tried a few stuff that they have there but no luck. Then again it could be that I didnt know how to add flags and such. If you can help I would appreciate it. I have added my web.xml

Comment: Sadly I only have one instance of atmosphere-cometd 1.0.0 and jetty-websocket 7.6.4 (it commes from atmosphere), and they both come from tapestr-cometd

Comment: Can you share the maven dependency tree ?

Comment: I have added dependencies in my pom hope it helps

Comment: I am not sure I you wanted to me to somehow give you dependency tree (I am not sure how, I use Netbeans and there is graph option but I dont know how to list all of the underline dependencies to copy past them here)

Comment: You can view dependencies using `mvn dependencies:tree` (I am assuming you are using maven). Your pom.xml wont show transitive dependencies.

Comment: I have added the tree (tnx for the tip about maven)

Comment: Looking at the sourcecode it appears that the exception is thrown if a constructor of a given signature is not found. That is only possible if the class loader is loading a wrong copy of a class. That can happen if there are multiple copies of the atmosphere jar.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a corrupt jar. Can you try deleting the atmosphere and jetty jars from your maven cache and try again?

If that doesn't work, I notice that both tapestry-cometd and tapestry-test are bringing in different versions of jetty. Can you try removing the tapestry-test dependency from your pom.xml. If removing the dependency works, you will need to specify version 7.6.4 of the jetty dependencies in your pom.xml.

Comment: Just to clarify, once I remove the jars I should build the application in order to download new jars and try to run the application on tomcat 7 then, if it doesnt work I should remove tapestry-test and then add jetty 7.6.4 and then try that on tomcat 7. Is this what you meant?

Comment: 1. Delete maven jars and re-build to get new versions and try running you app. 2. If that doesn't work, remove tapestry-test from your pom and try running. 3. If step 2 worked, you can put tapestry-test back in your pom but you will need to specify versions for all of the jetty dependencies in your pom. Use version 7.6.4 because this is what atmosphere expects

Comment: Also, how are you running your webapp? Are you running through your IDE or maven? Or are you building a war and deploying it to a tomcat installation?

Comment: All of the above. I am using IDE to build the application using maven - when I run it locally I use jetty (everything works there). But I deploy application that was build to AWS on Tomcat 7 or 6 (right now I try to both so that takes some time to deploy and lunch), btw when you say jetty do you mean jetty-server, webapp or something else?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what might be clashing. Search for "jetty" in your dependency:tree above. From what I can see you might need to define versions for the following: org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.9:test
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
jetty:org.mortbay.jetty:jar:5.1.12:test
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.0.0.v20091005:test

Comment: So, you are deploying a war to AWS? In that case, I don't think that steps 2 and 3 will help at all since tapestry-test has a scope of "test" so should not be packaged in the war.

Comment: hmm...yea that would make sense, and I dont think that number 1 will work as well as I have done that before, however I still wont to try it on both 6 and 7 just in case. If it fails I will try to change the version of my dependencies as per your suggestion and see if that help

Comment: hm, now when I look I see that all of the configurations that you have named are from the test so they should really be changed as they cant influence this problem

Comment: It might be worth looking at what version of the jetty jars are packaged in to the war. Failing that, you might be best to ask this question on the atmosphere forums

Comment: both 6 and 7 failed to lunch. The version of jetty jars are 7.6.4v20120524 as I believe it should be. I know that when I tried to use 8.1.8.v20121106 for jetty-websocket the application lunched but it was just acting crazy I may need to try to override other jetty files the same way (however this version disabled cometd). I will try it again and see what happens

Comment: Ok, let me know how you go. If I get a few spare cycles I might try to get the tapestry-cometd-demo running on tomcat 6/7

Comment: sure I will keep you posted in either case. Thanks for looking into this. Let me know if you have any luck running this on top of Tomcat